# How to get first key of properties file

Tags: java, properties

Given the following properties file,

```
abc=10
bcd=20
cde=11
def=321
```

how can I get the first key of the property file (in this case `abc`)?

Comment: read first line from file and split it by "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `java.util.Properties`, basically. That's based on a hash table, which has no concept of ordering.

It's not clear what the context is, but if at all possible, use a known key as "the most important" or whatever you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [**stringPropertyNames()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) method , which return a Set keys.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
          prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
            Set<String> keys = prop.stringPropertyNames();
            TreeSet<String> sorted = new TreeSet<>(keys);
            System.out.println(sorted.iterator().next());//returns abc
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But remember that a call to stringPropertyNames() returns a Set which is un-ordered, this works only if your properties file is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an enumeration of the keys with the `propertyNames` method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames()

However, there is nothing in the API to guaruntee that the first one in the enumeration will be the first one in the file.  It is rather unusual to care about the ordering of a properties file - it might help to get a better answer if you can explain why you want this.

Answer (score 0):

As pointer out by JS above, if you want to have sense of ordering you shouldn't use properties. On the other hand if you already are using it/inherited in project, this code would work.

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        p.load("properties.txt");

        try {
            //set the properties value
            prop.getProperty("abc");
            }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: No, Ranjan doesn't know which is the first property, "abc" is just the case here

Comment: @Hazeem yes I know that that's why I said that he shouldn't use properties if he wanted to get first property. This will get the value of property regardless of ordering

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Ranjan.properties"));
String line, firstPropertyKey;
// loop ignore initial whitespace
while ((line = b.readLine())!=null && line.trim().equals(""));
// whitespace gone (or end of file reached)
if (line != null) firstPropertyKey = line.split("=")[0].trim();
```

Because the above code is confusing to inexperienced developers, the while loop can also be written like this:

```
while ((line = b.readLine())!=null && line.trim().equals("")) { /*no body*/ }
```

That is, it does not need a body, and the **if** statement is **OUTSIDE** the loop. Also note that the WHILE loop not only checks conditions but reads a line from the file and assigns it to the *line* variable.

Comment: if you put `break` in your if statement this would work, otherwise you would end up with the last key in the file. And also `line.trim().equals("")` is always going to be false in his example. So you will never enter the while loop

Comment: @ant look closely. Firstly, all blank lines are discarded UNTIL you get to the first non-blank line (that is what the WHILE loop is for). Thus, only the FIRST non-blank line is read, which is what the OP wants. We don't need a break. Notice the IF statement is outside the WHILE loop.

Comment: @ant just to be absolutely clear, the variable LINE is set each time we attempt to evaulate the WHILE loop. So the very first iteration of WHILE reads a line from buffer into LINE and then the remainder of the WHILE checks are evaluated. Yes, this is advanced stuff, but very powerful. Thankyou for asking about it, I hope many people learn these techniques.

Comment: good point there with if being outside of while, I overlooked it. But that kind of code writing (without curly braces, it's not ruby after all) is simply ugly and not very readable (as I was looking it for few seconds and saw that it was incorrect and was wrong). All in all thanks for your reply. That is not really advanced stuff, just looks ugly but non the less correct

Comment: @ant fair enough. I agree it can be confusing for anyone. Good point though, when posting to these forums especially should keep code very clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below codes. Enumeration as mentioned by other user won't give you the correct ordering but this method is helpful when you want to pass value from properties file into another method. For e.g anotherMethod(value);

```
try {
        File file = new File("jasper.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fileInput);
        fileInput.close();

        Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
        while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);

            if(value=="10"){
                doSomething();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## This is my jasper.properties file

```
key=bond.investment , value=10  
key=bond.encashment, value=15 
bond.investment=10  
bond.encashment=15
```

Comment: could you provide a bit of explanation to this code to improve your answer and to help future readers?